# How to add two negative binary numbers

Tags: arithmetic, binary

> Solve the following using two's complement binary numbers: $ (-111)_{10}-(110)_{10}=?$

$(-111)_{10}=(10010001)_2$ with 2s complement

$-(110)_{10}=(10010010)_2$ with 2s complement

But $10010001+ 10010010 = 100100011$ which is $(291)_{10}$

Is this not the right way to add with two's complement?

You can check here that the values I got are correct:

https://www.easycalculation.com/twos-complement.php

http://planetcalc.com/911/

Comment: You should get a negative result. Apply the 2s complement again to get the unsigned answer. Remember: the first bit is a sign bit.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom ah so it's actually correct but there's overflow from 8 bits.

Comment: Yep!${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$